# Issues with unsigned char return value and +=

Tags: c++

I have an odd problem when using the return result of a function and the += operator.  The function is very simple, one line that fetches a unsigned char value from an array. When I use the = operator to place it into a variable, the value comes out correct.  However, using the +=, the value comes out to be garbage.

Here is my code:

```
unsigned short value = 0;

value = this->memory->get(address) << 8; //this will work
value += this->memory->get(address) << 8; //this will set it to 52480 every time

unsigned char Memory::get(unsigned int address)
{
    return this->memory[address];
}
```

I figured that initializing value to zero would solve the problem; however, it does not.  Also, casting the return to unsigned short still does not solve it.

Comment: I would imagine that the `value` is getting assigned somewhere before the `+=`.  Have you stepped through with a debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An unsigned char is not big enough to be shifted 8 bits on virtually every platform. This is undefined behaviour, to shift larger than the byte size.

Comment: I have tried casting to unsigned short before the shift with no luck

Comment: @MooingDuck: UB explains anything you need it to. That's the whole point of UB. The cast would probably fix that, though.